# Vertically align text inside anchor

Tags: html, css

I have this piece of HTML:

```
<a href="href" class="my-a-class>
    <img alt="alt" src="/path/to/image.jpg" class="my-img-class" />&nbsp;My text
</a>
```

I need to vertically align "My text" without affecting the image in the anchor. I can't add any HTML tag, I need to do this only with CSS. Any suggestion?

Comment: So you have an anchor with an image and the text should be laying centered over the image?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You could do this using `.my-a-class { line-height: value }`. Replace `value` with the height of your image.

### Edit ---

These days it is much better to use flexbox for this:

```
.my-a-class {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Comment: @m4t1t0 no worries. It isn't a robust as the other solutions (you have to keep track of your image height) but it works in most cases :)

Comment: Just to make sure for people who use this: this won't work if your text is long enough to jump into the second line ...

Comment: Hi  trainoasis, Yah that's my problem now. My text has 2 lines

Comment: How do I make it work if my text is naturally multi-line unless I add width: 100% to styling?

Answer (score 3):

Align the image to the text:

```
.my-a-class img { vertical-align: middle; }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/hz6AV/

Answer (score 1):

Set for `a img{vertical-align:middle;}` or `.my-img-class{vertical-align:middle;}` It should work.

Comment: I think your solution is valid, but in my case it does not work (I don't know why)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
a {
    position:relative;
    height:11em;
}
a img{
    position: absolute:
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    margin-top:auto;
    margin-bottom:auto;
}
```

or

```
.my-a-class {
    position:relative;
    height:11em;
}
.my-a-class .my-img-class{
    position: absolute:
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    margin-top:auto;
    margin-bottom:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Proper Way to Align Images and Icons with Anchor Tags is

In your css

```
a {
   background: transparent url(/images/your_image) scroll no-repeat left center;
   padding: 2px 0px 2px 20px; //fit as you need
}
```

In your HTML

```
<a href="url">Text</a>
```